# how to over come the issue of object slicing in c++

Tags: c++, object-slicing

How should I get rid of the problem with object slicing in c++.

In my application if the derived `class` has some dynamically allocated pointer and derived `class` object is assigned to base `class` object, the behavior is memory corruption!

Comment: This is easily the worst-presented question I have seen in a long time.  Voting to close on principle.

Comment: Actually this is the reason of bad design..Your design definitely do not follow the OOP principal.. Define the pointer in the base class.. Never change the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your design. You may have to change certain design criteria to get rid of it. One of the options is to have an overloaded `operator =` and copy constructor in your base `class` for particular derived `class`.

```
class Derived;
class Base
{
//...
private:
  Base (const Derived&);
  Base& operator = (const Derived&);  // private and unimplemented
};
```

Now if you attempt to do something like following:

```
Derived d;
Base b;
b = d; // compiler error
```

it will result in compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. you should solve the problem with the pointer. if you want to assign Obj2 to Obj1, override assign operator (operator=)